# Unable to overfit using MLP

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm building a 5-class classifier with a private dataset. Each data sample has 67 features and there are about 40000 samples. Samples of a particular class were duplicated to overcome class imbalance problems (hence 40000 samples).

With a one-vs-one multi-class SVM, I am getting an accuracy of ~79% on the validation set. The features were standardized to get 79% accuracy. Without standardization, the accuracy I get is ~72%. Similar result when I tried 50-fold cross validation.

Now moving on to MLP results,

**Exp 1:**

- *Network Architecture:* [67 40 5]
- *Optimizer:* Adam
- *Learning Rate:* exponential decay of base learning rate
- *Validation Accuracy:* ~45%
- *Observation:* Both training accuracy and validation accuracy stops improving.

**Exp 2:**
Repeated **Exp 1** with batchnorm layer

- *Validation Accuracy:* ~50%
- *Observation:* Got 5% increase in accuracy.

**Exp 3:**

To overfit, increased the depth of MLP. A deeper version of **Exp 1** network

- *Network Architecture:* [67 40 40 40 40 40 40 5]
- *Optimizer:* Adam
- *Learning Rate:* exponential decay of base learning rate
- *Validation Accuracy:* ~55%

Thoughts on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Some things that could be happening:

1. You do not have enough parameters in your hidden Layer to learn. Try something like [67, 512, 5] or expand deeper with something like [67, 1024, 256, 5]. The idea is that your hidden layer may be too small to capture interactions between the attributes given the amount of training data you have.

A rule of thumb that I [have seen](http://hagan.okstate.edu/NNDesign.pdf#page=469) is:

```
Nh=Ns/(α∗(Ni+No))

Nh = number of hidden neurons.
Ni = number of input neurons.
No = number of output neurons.
Ns = number of samples in training data set.
α = an arbitrary scaling factor usually 2-10.
```

Which in your case gets you to like 5000 neurons, but since you are oversampling your classes, I would also suggest [under-sampling](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/234016/opinions-about-oversampling-in-general-and-the-smote-algorithm-in-particular) instead, and that gets you maybe to around 1024, which is fairly standard. The [67, 512, 5] configuration is pure gut reaction.

2. Learning rate is too high. Try starting with lower LR (like 10e-5). Sometimes this works with Adam.
3. Weight Initialization : double check you are using Xavier.